# Question with the order of creating asycnio task and await in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm learning about `asyncio`, `await` and `async` in Python. Here's the general part of the code, these are the two tasks that I want to try concurrency on.

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def brew_coffee():
    print('Start brewing coffee...')
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    return 'Coffee is ready!'
    
async def make_toast():
    print('Start making toast...')
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return 'Toast is ready!'
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Now, in `async def main()`, I have a problem:

**main 1**

If I use the below `main()` function, the concurrency won't happen, and the elapsed time is `5` seconds.

```py
async def main():
    now = time.time()
    result_coffee = await asyncio.create_task(brew_coffee())
    result_toast = await asyncio.create_task(make_toast())
  
    end = time.time()
    print(f'Elapsed time: {end - now:.2f}')
    print(f'{result_coffee} {result_toast}')
```

**main 2**

Yet, if I use this `main` function, the concurrency would happen, with the elapsed time `3` seconds.

```py
async def main():
    now = time.time()

    coffee_task = asyncio.create_task(brew_coffee())
    toast_task = asyncio.create_task(make_toast())
    result_coffee = await coffee_task
    result_toast = await toast_task

    end = time.time()
    print(f'Elapsed time: {end - now:.2f}')
    print(f'{result_coffee} {result_toast}')
```

**My Question**

1. Why does the order of creating async tasks and awaiting matter?
2. Why can't I just combine them into one line of code?

Comment: `await` means to wait until the task is finished. In main 1 you create (and therefore schedule for execution) and await the coffee-task before you even create the toast-task. In main 2 you create both tasks (therefore they can both run) before awaiting them.